# Laravel Eloquent Perform Live Search

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent, livesearch

I'm currently trying to implement a functionality for a live search.

I have a table with just one important column (a name).

Now if I type in an input field, for every letter I enter, the table is browsed for names beginning with the letters already entered.

I want to use Eloquent to get this data. But how can I do this? The found data should appear in a list beyond the input field (limited to 10 entries) and then be clickable, the clicked value then is transfered to the input field.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do that is to use [`jQuery Autocomplete`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) (click `remote`) or something similar to send AJAX requests. In Laravel you need to create route for this AJAX request, search for data in a DB with something like `where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')` and send results back as [json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses) data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For me, especially the AJAX request would be interesting, as well as how I can convert the data got from db to json and then use in the plugin you provided (or any other way to process the data then)